# Turning off "Build Automatically" in Eclipse, to avoid file permission collision with Git client

Tags: eclipse, git, sourcetree

I'm curious what the repercussions of turning off "Build Automatically" in Eclipse are.

The problem I'm facing is that I use *Atlassian SourceTree* for my git client, and 80% of the time when I'm performing a git-flow operation like finishing a hotfix, or finishing a release, git will fail the operation because of file permissions.  The permission issue is stemming from Eclipse, it notices the files change in the middle of the git-flow operation because it's monitoring those folders, and automatically begins the "Build" operation on the project to bring itself up to date.

Sometimes git can finish before Eclipse stomps on it, but most of the time it ends in a permission collision.  I then generally have to discard all changes, clean up the tree and start the git operation again.  About half the time I have to close Eclipse entirely before the file permissions are released.

Are there any obvious solutions besides turning off the auto build?

---

**EDIT:**  I should point out that this has nothing to do with eclipse build files, they are all ignored, the collisions are happening on source files.

Comment: See http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-52.htm.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Eclipse's behaviour to build automatically as soon as a file changes is simply undesired... Is it something you really need?

My advice would be to turn this off, or to set eclipse to only build when you perform the save action on some file...